# Resample scattered data points to fit a grid, using interpolation in Matlab

Tags: matlab, interpolation

I have 2701 scattered data points (Kx,Ky), and I want to interpolate them to fit a grid. Probably by using griddedInterpolant in Matlab, but I don't understand how the input values work and can't find any good examples fitting my problem, online. Especially what is the v(x,y)-function?

If someone could explain this to me like I'm 10 years old, that would be appreciated.

Values are calculated using this code, and then plotted using scatter(). This gives points scattered in a circular figure.

```
k = 29;
i = 1;

for psi = 0:pi/36:2*pi

    for x = psi-pi/36:-pi/36:psi-pi/2
        Kx(i) = k*(cos(x)-cos(psi));
        Ky(i) = k*(sin(x)-sin(psi));
        i = i + 1;
    end

    for x = psi:pi/36:psi+pi/2
        Kx(i) = k*(cos(x)-cos(psi));
        Ky(i) = k*(sin(x)-sin(psi));
        i = i + 1;
    end

end
```

Comment: Could you provide a bit more info on your data, or add some example points? Is y a function of x, and do you want to find the y value for equal spaced x values?

Comment: question edited with the code

Comment: Still not really clear what you are trying to achieve, what is your desired output?

Comment: You need `griddata`. See the example in the documentation: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/griddata.html

Comment: Edited your post, your two for-loops could be merged to one and that way the domain you map to (Kx,Ky) is clearer. You have a map from 2D to 2D so not sure you can plot it (unless you make a 3D plot with one of the Kx or Ky values as a color or take a combination of Kx,Ky values to plot - such as their norm). Most of matlab plots though are for scalar functions F: R^n ->R

Comment: desired output are the points in a grid (aligned horizontally and vertically) instead of scattered like they are now, I want to later append some other values (wave measurements) to these points and inverse fourier transform it. It's a part of diffraction tomography. 

Basically I want the points in a rectangular shape instead of circular

Comment: You got two sets of points, the first set of points has (psi,x) coordinates and the second set is the result of the mapping of the first set with coordinates (Kx,Ky). Which are you talking about? Neither is in a rectangular grid (the first set is in a skewed grid though so it could be translated to be rectangular). But for the second set (Kx,Ky) which are plotted as a disc, if you want them in a rectangular grid you have to tell us how you are thinking you could produce that.

Comment: In regards to `griddedInterpolant` you mentioned in your original question, function `v` would be a scalar function mapping the points `(psi,x)` to `(Kx,Ky)`. However, your function is not scalar, since `(Kx,Ky)` has two values.